# webdrivermanager java browser in docker wsl2 how to configure

Tags: java, docker, selenium, wsl-2, webdrivermanager-java

I'm trying to setup webdrivermanager java with a chrome browser in a docker container. I have a docker daemon running on my local Windows 10 machine on WSL2. The docker daemon url should be tcp://127.0.0.1:2375.

I have version 5.1.0 of webdrivermanager.

Some sample code

```
WebDriverManager
        .chromedriver()
        .browserInDocker()
        .dockerDaemonUrl("tcp://127.0.0.1:2375")
        .create();
```

I always get the following warning: WARN  io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.docker.DockerService - Docker is not available in your machine... local browsers are used instead

What is the correct setup for webdrivermanager in this case?

Answer (score 0):

For a local Docker engine, the method `dockerDaemonUrl()` should not be necessary.

Comment: I did another attempt without dockerDaemonUrl however I got the same warning Docker is not available in your machine

Answer (score 0):

The following attempt was successful. Adding avoidDockerLocalFallback did the trick. The DockerService of WebdriverManager always tries to resolve the docker daemon locally by default but is unsuccessful in case of a docker daemon running on WSL2.

```
WebDriverManager
    .chromedriver()
    .browserInDocker()
    .avoidDockerLocalFallback()
    .dockerDaemonUrl("tcp://127.0.0.1:2375")
    .create();
```